# how to install a prefPane on mac osx from commandline?

Tags: macos, command-line, osx-snow-leopard, installation

I'm automating some system installs and I need to install a prefPane.

something like `installer -pkg xxx.pkg -target /` that I use for installing .pkg files.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simple preference panes can be "installed" by moving them to

`/Users/yourname/Library/PreferencePanes/`

and "uninstalled" by removing them from there (just tested it with Secrets).

You can "launch" them using `open`.

Many preference panes install additional daemons/agents or system components upon launch or user action. You should be able to use AppleScript to perform these UI actions, but they're custom to each preference pane.

Comment: might be worth to mention the `/System/Library/PreferencePanes` as well. and, since I've already said that, why not rather than `/Users/yourname/` simply using the [tilde expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html) `~/`?

Comment: One tip if using command line - use `cp -r something.prefPane ~/Library/PreferencePanes` to install a pref pane for personal use.  Don't put a `/` after the prefPane argument - it is directory but the `/` makes `cp` do the wrong thing.